# php or db - which should I convert first? (from ASP classic; MS .access)

Tags: php, converters

php or db - which should I convert first? (from ASP classic; MS .access). Also, do you ou have any recommendations as to which converters to use.

Comment: If your database has the necessary tools, I would export the database as a comma delimited file, then import that comma delimited file into the new database.

Answer (score 0):

I would first convert the database, beceause that's the first thing you do when programming, structuring the data you'll be using isn't it?

About converters, I'd certainly use brain1.1, and wouldn't trust a bot to do this for me.